# How to work around the VC++ 2012 bug on generating operator = assignment and copy constructor?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, unique-ptr

I have a class. It has a member of unique_ptr.

```
struct A
{
    std::unique_ptr<int> m;
};
```

And the following statements should work

```
A a;
A b;
a = std::move(b);
std::swap(a, b);
```

However, VC++ 2012 has a bug in compiling the code. Is there any easy way to work around the bug besides manually generating your own copy constructor and assignment operator with R-Value argument? Automatically generating (such as by macros) are fine.

Comment: nope, sorry.  Out of luck.

Comment: @aaronman: All versions of MSVC will try to copy `A` instead of move it, and then generate a mysterious compiler error that won't tell you where it tried to do the copy.  Here it is in action: http://rise4fun.com/Vcpp/Kd1F

Comment: @MooingDuck but will it work if you implement the mctor or massign operator

Comment: @aaronman: yes, if you write a move constructor/move assignment, or declare a private copy constructor/copy assignment _in A_  it will behave correctly.

Comment: Right, Visual C++ does not (yet) generate the implicit move constructor or move assignment operator.  (Implicit move operation generation was added to C++11 very late during standardization, and support for move semantics was added to the Visual C++ compiler relatively early, before the specification changed.  The compiler has yet to be updated.)

Comment: @MooingDuck Does this include VS2013?

Comment: @NeilKirk: I'm not actually certain.  I certainly _hope_ they fixed it for VS2013....

Comment: @MooingDuck This is not implemented in Visual C++ 2013.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, other than macros there is no other easy way of getting around this bug.

Comment: @MooingDuck  I'm sure you mean downvotes, but that's OK.  I understand. LOL

Comment: what macros can help?  Like a variardic one that lists the members and the type, and writes a move construct and assign?

Comment: @Yakk Maybe. I remember there is one to make make_unique work for VC++. There may be a similar way to do it here.